# Pythontex: Only run the modified code

Tags: pythontex

I use \pyc{`python code`} to print matplotlib plots to pdf. I have many such huge plots within a document. Recently noticed that, though I am running pythontex without `rerun=always` option, all the previous not modified codes are also executed, leading to minutes of execution time (taking same time as that of `rerun=always` enabled), whereas it only takes a few seconds while running independently (from another document). This was not supposed to happen as per Pythontex documentation:

> By default, PythonTEX will rerun code that has been modified or that
>   produced errors on the last run.

Does anybody else face the same problem? Is there something special to be done to compile the modified code alone in pythontex?

Comment: Take a look at latexmk. There is a latemkrc file to automate the use of Pythontex.

Comment: Are you running all Python code in a single session? If so, everything will run whenever anything is modified. In that case, you might try splitting code into independent sessions (for example, `\begin{pycode}[fig1session]` and `\pyc[fig1session]{<code>}` for figure 1, etc.).

Comment: I did not explicitly mention sessions, in that case are all the codes running in single session?

Comment: @G.Poore. I ran my codes by mentioning different sessions, and yes it is now working as expected. Thanks.